# How can I return JSON from node.js backend to frontend without reloading or re-rendering the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, post

I am working with node.js.

I want to press a search button, make some rest api calls to another server in the backend and return the json back to the front end, and reload a div in the front end so that I won't have to refresh the page. Now I know I can reload just a div with jQuery or just Javascript dom manipulation.

But how do I make it call a method on the server side? I could have a submit button and it will make a post request and I can catch it and make my api calls from there, however from the node.js side, when I return, I will have to render the page again. How do I go about returning JSON from the back end to the front end without re-rendering or refreshing my page?

Thanks.

Comment: You're talking about AJAX right? [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Are you simply asking how to do AJAX from browser to server? Or are you asking how to make HTTP call from the server to another server? Cause I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Or are you asking how to use node.js to only show json with no html?

Comment: I'm asking how to do AJAX from browser to server. I want the browser to call the server, which will make some REST calls, and return JSON back to browser. Without refresh.

Comment: I tried to use jQuery AJAX, but I couldn't make rest calls to another server because of Same origin policy.

Comment: So you want to call a server which is on a different domain then the web page?? That's **entirely** different question then the one you posted. :) Read about JSONP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following demonstrates how to make a basic AJAX request.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tWdhy/1/

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/', //the URL to your node.js server that has data
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data){
        //"data" will be JSON. Do what you want with it. 
        alert(data);
    }); 
});
```

​
    ​

Comment: AH. So I can call my own /search, which in turn will make the API call to the remote server. Then this won't violate same origin policy and I have what I need, right?

Comment: As long as you can get to your node server without changing the domain, port, and protocol Example:(http ://localhost:8080) then you should be fine. Otherwise you'll have to implement a JSONP service which is something fairly different.

Comment: Awesome, thank you, I think this will work. I shall try it later!

Answer (score 5):

http://expressjs.com/

Roughly something like this on the server:

```
var app = express.createServer();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/search', function(req, res){
   search_form = req.body;  // <-- search items
   MySearch.doSearch(search_form,function(err,items) {
       res.send(items);
   });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

You will have to implement the doSearch code to return whatever you are searching....

Client:

```
   <script>
   $.ajax( {
      url: '/search',
      data: search_form,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(items) {
          /* do something with items here */
          // You will likely want a template so you don't have to format the string by hand
        for( var item in items ) {
           $('#results').append('<div>'+item.interestingField+'</div>);
        }
      }
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: When res.send() executes, how will the front end receive and use the data?

Comment: This looks like it's something he already has. I think he needs the client portion.

Comment: Brandon is right, I'm not sure how to code up the client to use that data.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing comments (sadly, the question is not asked properly): what you want is to make an AJAX call to the server which is on a **different** domain, then the JavaScript. Normally you can't do that because of the same origin policy. There are however some hacks:

1) Use jQuery's AJAX with `dataType: 'jsonp'`. You should read and learn more about JSONP.

2) Make an AJAX call to your domain and let the server call another server. With Node.JS you can use this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.request(/* options */);
```

See [the documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest).